# Is there any library that converts C# objects with references into dojox.json.ref compatible JSON?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, dojo

I would like to serialize some .NET objects with circular references into JSON that is compatible and can be parsed and resolved with the Dojo library `dojox.json.ref`. [This library](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/17/json-referencing-in-dojo/) allows serialization of the following:

```
var obj = {};
obj.me = obj;
```

like this:

```
var jsonWithCircularRef = dojox.json.ref.toJson(obj);
obj = dojox.json.ref.fromJson(jsonWithCircularRef);
obj.me == obj // -> true, the reproduced object will
    //have a property named "me" with a value of itself.
```

The JSON (with references intact) would look like this:

```
{"id":"1","me":{"$ref":"1"}}
```

What I want is code or a library that allows me to, on the server side using C#, convert objects with circular references to JSON (with references intact, as above) that can be parsed by the `dojox.json.ref` library. Is there anything already out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON.Net (http://json.codeplex.com/) library can serialize object graphs with preserved references.  The syntax of the resulting JSON is nearly identical to your example, the only difference is the 'id' is '$id' instead.  I do not know if Dojo can handle this.  If not, the JSON.Net library is open source so you could add an option for Dojo compatible syntax.

The JSON.Net library is also nicely documented.  Here is the page on preserving references: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/PreserveObjectReferences.html.

Comment: Worked perfectly, just removed the $ and everything was fine.. Thanks!